# /etc/init.d/nginx not executable

Tags: nginx, debian, passenger

I searched on the internet for a while now and I don't find a solution so I am asking here: My question is, why is this file (`/etc/init.d/nginx`) not executeable?

I was following the tutorial of [Alex](https://alexpearce.me/2012/06/setting-up-a-vps/) yesterday and I got into an issue. Everything worked until the `service nginx restart`-command. When I try to run this command I will get

```
 nginx: You don't have permissions to execute nginx.
```

After googling some time I found a potential answer, but this was already done in the tutorial/walkthrough of Alex:

```
 $ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
```

**Some info if you don't want to read the tutorial:**

- I am using Nginx (as you will know when reading this bit)
- It's installed it with Passenger and then imported a Nginx Init-script and the nginx.conf file from scratch.
- Oh and I am running Debian instead of Ubuntu, but that shouldn;t be the problem, or?

So I would be very thankful if anyone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: why not run `sudo service` instead of just `service`

Comment: I also tried ’sudo’ but it also doesn't help. I am also the root user.

Comment: `sudo service nginx start` said no permissions ?

Comment: From today on it just **don't return anything**.

Comment: then maybe there is something wrong with your nginx, try running `sudo nginx -t` i think that is how you test your nginx configuration

Comment: So, now the next problem is: I get permission error.
But I figured out that I can use the ’nginx’ command to start the server including Passenger.
Thanks for your help. But I also would like to access the init script.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: I am also having the same problem did you find solution for this

Comment: @Magnum I reseted my server and done it after my own instructions: https://gist.github.com/iDuuck/708a7e2aa0d851a738ed

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the variables in your init script are correct:

Here's an example script: http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu

For instance, I had to change NGINX_CONF_FILE="/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf" to NGINX_CONF_FILE="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" and it solved my problem.